# How to save the event in javascript cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

This pop-up window. After the client visited the site in 30 seconds, a window will automatically appear. After closing the window disappears. But when the client goes to another page, the script starts to work ( after refreshing the page). How to remember closing the modal window at the time of visiting the client's site?

```
<div id="parent_popup">
            <div id="popup">
                message message message message message message message 
                <a class="close"title="close" onclick="document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='none';">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>
 #parent_popup{
     padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#popup{
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 520px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border: 10px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
     border-radius: 15px;
}
.close{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    top: -24px;
    width: 24px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 122, 200, 0.8);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
            var delay_popup = 5000;setTimeout("document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='block'", delay_popup);

</script>
```

Comment: You can not do that - javascript is run in a sandbox and does not carry over

Comment: How to save the event in javascrip cookies?

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript write a function to store a cookie if it doesn't exist then set the cookie that lasts for 30 mins. ** Writen not tested

```
// get cookie 
var cookie_email = Cookies.get('example');

if(!cookie_email){

 // show popup
 var delay_popup = 5000;setTimeout("document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='block'", delay_popup);

 // set cookie to expire after 30 mins 
 var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 30;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });

}
```

Comment: I dont think that will allow for a window to pop up 30 minutes later after going to another page? or whatever the OP was